# Inserting dataframe into a normalized Table

Tags: python, pandas

having a database with normalized tables, in which most fields are foreign keys relating to other tables, how does one go about inserting a plain-and-simple DataFrame? That Dataframe, of course, holds the actual representations of the values e.g. Names, Cities, Item Names etc. The tables themselves, mostly expect a serial ID.

Does Pandas contain some functions which make such inserts easy? Or should one go to SQLAlchemy perhaps?

Thanks!

Comment: So how are the foreign keys related to other tables, can you explain by an example?

Comment: Most tables simply reference one-another by using their id's. E.g. instead of using 'city', they use the id column of city.